# Django - If my template tag takes the context and the context is changed, are its new variables accessible in the rest of my page?

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I have a template tag that takes the context. In it I add a variable to my context. It seems this variable prints correctly in the template which includes my template tag (let's call it "desktop"). But in the the template which includes THAT template, it no longer has the variable.

I've googled the django docs because I'm curious as to what's going on here. Is my template tag's context variable only available within the template that includes it and not beyond, as it seems?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge a template tag's rendering context only applies to the template that it's rendering. It won't overwrite a context variable used in other places in the template. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was just curious to find that my variable was printing in the template that contains the include to my templatetag. I was expecting it to be limited to, as you say, the template it's rendering. But nope, looked to go one "step" up but not beyond.

Answer (score 2):

In the Django library, django.template.base you have the *parse_bits* function.  In this function, the view context is copied into a new variable.

```
if takes_context:
    if params[0] == 'context':
        params = params[1:]
    else:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            "'%s' is decorated with takes_context=True so it must "
            "have a first argument of 'context'" % name)
```

And in the class *InclusionNode* class render function, a new context object is created to render the template of the template tag:

```
class InclusionNode(TagHelperNode):

            def render(self, context):
                """
                Renders the specified template and context. Caches the
                template object in render_context to avoid reparsing and
                loading when used in a for loop.
                """
                resolved_args, resolved_kwargs = self.get_resolved_arguments(context)
                _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

                t = context.render_context.get(self)
                if t is None:
                    if isinstance(file_name, Template):
                        t = file_name
                    elif isinstance(getattr(file_name, 'template', None), Template):
                        t = file_name.template
                    elif not isinstance(file_name, six.string_types) and is_iterable(file_name):
                        t = context.template.engine.select_template(file_name)
                    else:
                        t = context.template.engine.get_template(file_name)
                    context.render_context[self] = t
                new_context = context.new(_dict)
                # Copy across the CSRF token, if present, because
                # inclusion tags are often used for forms, and we need
                # instructions for using CSRF protection to be as simple
                # as possible.
                csrf_token = context.get('csrf_token', None)
                if csrf_token is not None:
                    new_context['csrf_token'] = csrf_token
                return t.render(new_context)
```

So it should not propagate the templatetag context to the calling template.

Comment: Thanks Cedric, but as per my live demonstration to you, the templatetag context is still available in the template that does the templatetag include (and only below the include, and not any level higher in the series of includes) x_x